# Post method acts like get method when submitting a form

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

```
//db connect
    $server     = 'localhost';
    $username   = 'root';
    $password   = '';
    $database   = 'resort';
    $connect    = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password ) or die(mysqli_error.'error connecting to db');
//select database
    mysqli_select_db ($database, $connect) or die(mysqli_error.'error selecting db');/*Jquery Function*/<script>
                    $(function(){
    //CONTACT FORM AJAX SUBMIT
    $('#contactForm').submit(function(){
          $.ajax({
        url:'mailer.php',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
           success: function(data){
         if(data.error){
            $('#error').css('display','block');
        }else {
            $('#note').show();
            $('#error').hide();
            $(".contact-form").hide();
        }
    }
   });
   return false;
 });
});
                    </script>
```

[image: Database Connectivity][image: Contact Form]
    issue is that when i am trying to click on submit the webpage refreshes and the contents are shown in the url. Errors does not occur so no way to find out what the problem is. I am trying to build a contact form that can send mail. So you will also get some code related to it.The main issue is that why the page refreshes every time and why there is not any error if, database is connected or not,query written for insertion of data is correct or not, variables are correctly declared or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your images are already in the right format then use `Convert.ToBase64String Method (Byte[])` method to convert them to a base64 string and send this base64 string back. 
where you can use the string in the `src` attribute of the img tag to display the images. Which would be something like

```
<img src=”data:<MIMETYPE>;base64,<BASE64_ENCODED_IMAGE>”>
```

Comment: <asp:Image ID="imgItems" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#"data:image/png;base64," +  Eval(Convert.ToBase64String("PictureBinary")) %>' Width="200px" Height="250px" />

Comment: i thought we are talking about asp.net web api. this looks like asp.net code

Comment: ya it is and i have just started using web api so i do not know much about it

Comment: i want to use web api service in another website so it is developed in asp.net

Answer (score 1):

What you can do instead of my first answer and this is a more preferred way by me. Is Instead of sending the varbinary/base64 in the response omit the field. Send send back your other fields of response with id. 
Make a separate action method that would take the Id and send you back the image. Image nw can be sent back just in the binary format using one of the `FileActionResult` Overloads.
**--Advantages**
 1. Now the web api will return a smaller response hence will be faster.
 2. Since image is being loaded separately. You can gracefully show loaders till they haven't loaded.

Comment: Please be specific i am not getting it